# Java PropertyChangeListner

Tags: java

if I send two null values as below.

```
pcl.firePropertyChange("name", null, null)
```

it will recognize this as a change and fires 
`propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)`.

Is this a bug? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why is it a bug? - you did fire a property change

Comment: if both old value and new value are equal it should not fire propertychange event. So in my case both old value and new value is null. Then why it should fire propertychange event ?

Comment: no worries found the trick. http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/12/15/javabeans-propertychangesupport-trick/

Comment: this is not a bug, this is the specified behaviour. It means something like: "Something has changed, please read the values directly from the bean"

Answer (score 1):

It's working as defined in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html#firePropertyChange%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
No event is fired if old and new are equal and non-null.
```

So no bug.